# delete all union como consulta parametrizada

Tags: ms-access, delphi

Estoy usando este codigo para eliminar registros con datetimepicker

```
begin
nuevo_query.close;
nuevo_query.sql.clear;
nuevo_query.sql.add('delete from tabla1 where fecha between  :fecha1 and :fecha2 ');
nuevo_:query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').DataType := ftdate;
nuevo_query..Parameters.ParamByName('fecha1').Value :=  Trunc(Datetimepicker1.Date);
nuevo_query.Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').DataType := ftdate;
 nuevo_query..Parameters.ParamByName('fecha2').Value :=  Trunc(Datetimepicker2.Date);
nuevo_query.execsSQL;
query_grilla.close;
query_grilla.open;
end;
```

Lo que busco hacer es unir dos tablas mas para poder eliminar registros de las otras dos tablas que figuran en la grilla.
Esta es mi consulta que tiene la grilla

```
select * from tabla1 WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 01 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2019
union
select * from tabla2 WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 01 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2019
union
select * from tabla3 WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 01 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2019
```

Comment: Los delete son por tabla. tenes que hacer 3 deletes

Comment: Qué capa de conexión estás utilizando? o, en otras palabras, de que tipo es el componente `nuevo_query`?

Comment: nuevo_query es un componente ADO, lo utilizo porque tenia un problema en tiempo de ejecución y no me permitía seguir operando el resto de los registros

Comment: @gbianchi te referís de esta forma    nuevo_query.sql.add('delete from tabla1 where fecha between  :fecha1 and :fecha2 ');    nuevo_query.sql.add('delete from tabla2 where fecha between  :fecha1 and :fecha2 ');                   nuevo_query.sql.add('delete from tabla3 where fecha between  :fecha1 and :fecha2 ');

Comment: exacto @pablo. no se pueden hacer delete multiples.. no es lo mismo que un select

Answer (score 1):

Con ADO puedes ejecutar multiples consultas (`SELECT`) en una sóla ejecución ya acceder a los Datasets resultantes, pero no puedes hacer lo mismo con `INSERT`/`UPDATES`.

En este caso, como alternativas tienes:

- Hacerlo desde Delphi utilizando un procedimiento o un blucle para lanzar varios `ExecSQL` (uno por tabla).
- Hacerlo desde la Base de Datos utilizando una `Function` o un  `Stored Procedure`. En tu caso como parece que estás utilizando Access y no dispone de estas opciones, sólo te queda la primera.